# NoReverseMatch at /student/test/ Reverse for 'single_quiz' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['quiz/(?P<quiz_id>[0-9]+)/$']

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

revere match error occurred when passing id. but works fine when added manually.it shows NoReverseMatch error. I am unable to figure out where this is coming from. Should I add the traceback too ?

template

```
    <div style="padding: 100px 270px;">
    {% for a in applied%}
    {{a.job.quiz.id}}

    <a href="{% url 'single_quiz' a.job.quiz.id %}">{{a.job.quiz}}</a>
    
    {%endfor%}
    </div>
```

views.py

```
def single_quiz(request, quiz_id):
     print(quiz_id)
     quiz = get_object_or_404(Quiz, pk=quiz_id)
     print(quiz)
     num_questions = len(quiz.question_set.all())
     try:

         unique = Result.objects.get(user=request.user,quiz=quiz)

     except Result.DoesNotExist:
          unique = False



      # deletes quiz and returns to home if no questions created
    if num_questions == 0:
         quiz.delete()
         all_quiz_list = Quiz.objects.all()
         context = {
         'all_quiz_list': all_quiz_list,
          }
          return render(request, 'quiz/index.html', context)

    quiz.num_questions = num_questions
    quiz.save()

    # resets accuracy info to 0
    request.session["num_correct"] = 0
    request.session["num_wrong"] = 0

    context = {
        'quiz': quiz,
        'num_questions': num_questions,
        'unique': unique,
    }

    return render(request, 'quiz/single_quiz.html', context)

def TestStudents(request):
     applied=Applicants.objects.filter(applicant=request.user)
     context={
        'applied':applied
      }
     return render(request,'student/test_list.html',context)
```

urls.py

```
path('<int:quiz_id>/', views.single_quiz, name='single_quiz'),
```

Comment: Try sending named parameter.
`<a href="{% url 'single_quiz' quiz_id=a.job.quiz.id %}">{{a.job.quiz}}</a>`
As mentioned by TEST, make sure you're passing correct context to template from view.

Comment: still not working after changes and context is correct

Comment: Does each `a` have a `job`? Does each `job` have a `quiz`? If not then add `if ... else` around url generation.

Comment: don't understand if is everithing under `if num_questions == 0:` or not

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this :-

```
    {% for a in quiz %}


    <a href="{% url 'single_quiz' a.id %}">{{a.job.quiz}}</a>
    
    {% endfor %}
```

> I didn't see any variable named `applied` in your whole view. Make sure you are successfully passing all the variables.

Comment: a.id is different from the id for the quiz. not working

Comment: Okay, BUT i didn't see the `quiz` variable on your `view`.